# Designing Responsive Map Search Results

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out the best way to use Bootstrap to design a responsive search results page.  On desktop I plan on having a results list on the left and a map on the right - similar to https://www.google.com/maps/search/bars+near+10001/@40.751591,-73.9957831,15z/am=t .

However on smaller devices I want to have two buttons (toggles) between list and map results.  I'm just not sure how to do that with bootstrap.

Comment: show us what you've tried! a js-fiddle or bootply would be best

Comment: If you want to use bootstrap, here's what I can suggest. Make a JS/jQuery function that makes a toggle button visible and hides the map if the size of the screen goes below a particular limit. Then define that toggle button in such a way that you can use it to show/hide maps and list view. If you're looking for responsive maps, [this](https://gist.github.com/ranveeraggarwal/9333726) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get close without any javascript, with `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs`: **http://www.bootply.com/aIwaKqchLW**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Show Map</button>
</div>
...
<div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
  <h2>Map</h2>
```

Then use js attached to the button to toggle visibility of either map or results... which I don't have time to sort out right now:( maybe if no-one else does I'll come back

Comment: Thanks this is helping me get started in the right direction.